# Concat multiple videos with diferent audio and subtitle streams count using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to add a watermark logo to a video (uploaded by users) and concat it with an Intro. The resulting video must have same format as input video.

The problem starts when the uploaded video has more than one audio stream and includes subtitles.

I solved the audio problem by using something like this command.

`ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i input.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=480:270,setdar=16/9 [a]; [1:v] scale=480:270,setdar=16/9 [b]; [2:0] scale=480:270 [wm]; [b][wm] overlay[ov]; [a][0:a:0][0:a:0] [ov][1:a:0][1:a:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=2 [vd] [a0] [a1]" -map "[vd]" -map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -y output.mkv`

But the output does not contain subtitles.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i input.mkv -itsoffset 4.5 -i input.mkv -i logo.png
  -filter_complex
     "[0:v] scale=480:270,setdar=16/9 [a];
      [1:v] scale=480:270,setdar=16/9 [b];
      [3:0] scale=480:270 [wm];
      [b][wm] overlay[ov];
      [a][0:a:0][0:a:0] [ov][1:a:0][1:a:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=2 [vd] [a0] [a1]"
  -map "[vd]" -map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -map 2:s? -c:s copy -y output.mkv
```

Once you specify any map statements, only those mapped streams are included. So, you have to explicitly map any subtitle streams. Since there may not be one, I've added a trailing `?` to indicate conditional assignment.

I've fed the input video twice, because the subtitle timestamps will be wrong in the output as the intro now precedes the video. A timestamp offset is added to the 2nd input and the subtitle is mapped from that feed. The `itsoffset` value should be equal to the duration of the intro (in seconds). There shouldn't be any need to transcode the subtitles.