# Concatenating an image with a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that is downloaded with [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). I want to create a video that is made out of an image and the downloaded video, using `ffmpeg` and the loop function.

```
./ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy merged.mp4
```

Inside of my list.txt file is

```
file word_img.jpg
file youtube_video.mp4
```

Running the command at the bottom creates a new video. It's just that the it's the same exact thing as the youtube video. The other image never gets added. Could this have to do with the encoding?

I also tried another approach which went something like this.

```
./ffmpeg -t 125 -async 1 -i youtube_video.mp4\
   -t 5 -i word_img.jpg \
   -filter_complex "[0]loop=149:1:0[bgheld5]; \
                    [1]loop=149:1:0[fgheld5]; \
                    [bgheld5][fgheld5]overlay=eof_action=pass" out.mp4
```

This sort of works. There is a static image that get displayed for 5 seconds and then the 30 second youtube video gets played. The problems is that the audio and the video of the youtube video are out of sync by about 5 seconds.

Running `./ffmpeg -i img.jpg` returns the following

```
Input #0, image2, from 'img.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1258 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x356 [SAR 96:96 DAR 160:89], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Running `./ffmpeg -i video.mp4` returns the following

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
Duration: 00:02:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 575 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x356 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:89], 440 kb/s, 24.98 fps, 24.98 tbr, 25k tbn, 49.95 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 
10/28/2018.
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/28/2018
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Instead of showing us the source code (which is just distracting), please show the actual ffmpeg command that is being run (e.g., `echo` it), and the full, uncut command line output of that process. Also, I don't see your `list.txt` contents or the ffmpeg command that you are using to read that `list.txt` file (which I assume is the one that produces incorrect output), including its command-line output.

Comment: @slhck My apologies. I updated my question to include only the commands that I ran. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: That's much better, thanks. I think it's confusing that you wrote "I have two videos" where in fact what you really want is *one* video which is composed of a looping image for five seconds and then the downloaded YouTube video? I'll write up an answer…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have a static image file and a video that you would like to concatenate. The image should be shown for five seconds without audio; the video should follow.

You can run everything in one command with:

```
ffmpeg \
  -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 5 -i image.png \
  -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc \
  -i video.mp4 \
  -filter_complex " \
    [2:v]scale=320:240,setsar=sar=1[video]; \
    [0:v][1:a][video][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 \
  " output.mp4
```

What it does:

- Specify the image as input `0`, looping it up to a length of 5 s at 24 fps.
- Specify silent audio as second input `1`, which is needed for concatenation
- Specify the video as third input `2`
- Scale the video to the same size as the image (but you could of course also scale the image… just swap the input identifiers `2:v` to `1:v` and rename the label `video`)
- Set its sample aspect ratio to 1 (this is a quick fix for differing SARs; you may have to be more explicit like shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/1191054/48078))
- Concatenate logo + silent audio with the video.

You can also use the `scale2ref` filter (another example [here](https://superuser.com/a/1100429/48078)) to scale the logo to the video:

```
-filter_complex " \
  [0:v][2:v]scale2ref[logo][video]; \
  [logo]setsar=sar=1[logo];  \
  [logo][1:a][video][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 \
"
```

Comment: That throws an error `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 320x240, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x356, SAR 96:96)
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0x7ffabec59800] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument`

The image and the video both appear to have the same dimensions

Comment: Apparently they have different sizes – make sure that what the log shows is matching for both inputs. Your image seems to be 640x354, and the video 320x240.  Can you please update your question and show `ffmpeg -i image.jpg` and `ffmpeg -i youtube_video.mp4` console output?

Comment: Yep. No prob. I updated my question

Comment: See the updated answer. Maybe the `scale2ref` filter works; it scales up the logo to the video size. You have to manually set the sample/display aspect ratio if they differ. See also https://superuser.com/a/1191054/48078

Comment: How would it work if I wanted to add have a sequence where there is the video playing for it's full duration followed by an image playing for 5 seconds followed by the video playing for its full duration again?

Comment: Same idea, just add more inputs and supply them to the `concat` filter by label, examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/435093.